# Adding a preview to a Framelayout using the Addview(preview)

Tags: android-camerax

I am trying to add a view to a frame layout using addview(preview) and whenever I add the preview kotlin asks me to provide a preview when I have provided a view and a view when  I have provided a preview. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong.

'''

```
    val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(viewBinding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
                }

            frmLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.fr);
            frmLayout!!.addView(preview)
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the [PreviewView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView).

```
val preview = Preview.Builder().build().also {       
    it.setSurfaceProvider(viewBinding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
}

frmLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.fr);
// Change this line here:
frmLayout!!.addView(viewBinding.viewFinder)
```